# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7575932.' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this legacy code that started failing…

```
UPDATE B2C 
SET B2C.dborderid = A.order_number__c
FROM b2csf B2C 
JOIN Alemania A ON B2C.actualid = A.salesforce_id
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7201799-' to data type int.

I went ahead and changed it to:

```
UPDATE B2C 
SET B2C.dborderid = (CASE 
                        WHEN Isnumeric (a.order_number__c) = 1 
                           THEN CAST(a.order_number__c AS INT) 
                     END)
FROM b2csf B2C 
JOIN Alemania A ON B2C.actualid = A.salesforce_id
```

And now I get

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7575932.' to data type int.

My questions now are:

- how can I avoid this error? I don’t mind for example losing '7575932.' value.(Ideally I would like to discard '7575932.' value)
- I am trying my best to follow best practices... is changing the column `DBorderid` to `nvarchar` the only "best practice" alternative?

(*I am using SQL Server 2008*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `... WHEN Isnumeric (a.order_number__c) = 1 ...` use `... WHEN Isnumeric (a.order_number__c + '.0e0') = 1 ...`

Comment: it worked great, thanks, now I get: Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The conversion of the nvarchar value '3545427103' overflowed an int column. The statement has been terminated. Is there any in-line elegant/best practice solution?

Comment: @Chicago1988 how about like this additional condition `case when cast('3545427103' as numeric(38,0)) between -2147483648 and 2147483648 then ...`

Comment: sounds good, but  bad data will keep coming... So it will eventually fail again... I can't believe I can't find a solution for this simple thing...

Comment: @Chicago1988 did you try case inside case `...case when Isnumeric (a.order_number__c + '.0e0') = 1 then case when cast(a.order_number__c as numeric(38,0)) between -2147483648 and 2147483648 then ... ` it will check all possible options